# how to dynamically refresh and display the list with jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm adding comment section and have some troubles with displaying them. Here is my saving method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddComment(int id_usr,string comment)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       Comments kom = new Comments();
       kom.DateComment = DateTime.Now;
       kom.Id_usr = id_usr;
       kom.Comment = comment;
       db.Comments.Add(kom);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return Json(kom);
   }
   return Json(null);
}
```

getting comment value and save onClick

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var idurl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
$('#submit').click(function () {
  console.log('click')
  $.ajax({
  url: '/form/AddComment',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
        comment: $("#Comments_Comment").val(),
        id_usr: idurl,
  },
  success: function (data) {
         console.log(data), //to this point all is working
```

my attempt to display it in list looks like:(need only datetime and comment text)

```
$("#Comments2_Comment").empty(); 
data.forEach(function (item) {
var rows = "<ul>"
+ "<li>" + item.DateComment + "</li>"
+ "<li>" + item.Comment + "</li>"
+ "</ul>";
$('#Comments2_Comment').append(rows);
});

},
```

unfortunately it gives me:"TypeError: data.forEach is not a function"
How it should look like?

I want to get something like this

2019-06-19: qwertyu

2019-06-19: asdfghj

Comment: Ensure `data` is an array and not an object

Comment: You are trying to iterate over Object. You have to debug your `data` variable. You can iterate only over arrays.

Comment: `data` is an object, so how can i display it in top of my comments list?

Comment: Please add to your question example of your data object and we will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a quick example of what you could do. I just created a JSON string and parsed It into an object for demonstration but you would use your own object. Then you just need to loop through It using jQuery's **$.each** and you're all set. Let me know if It helps you.

```js
let data = '{"names":[{"name":"Michael S."},{"name":"Jim H."},{"name":"Pam B."}]}'

data = JSON.parse(data)

let str = '';

$.each(data.names, (key, val) => {
  str += '<ul><li>' + val.name + '</li></ul>'
})

$('#myDiv').empty().append(str)
```

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: I just needed to `$('#MyEditor').empty()` and `$('#MyDiv').append("<li>" + data.DateComment + '  ' + data.Comment + "</li>");` ty for answer it was helpful